# Standardization in a sample - proof

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing, random-variables

So the proof for standardizing a normally distributed random variable follows this structure:

Suppose we have random variable $x$ defined as $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. Then we define $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, and we'll show that $\mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$ and $Var[Z]=1$.

First, we show $\mathbb{E}[Z] =0$ follows from the linearity of expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{\sigma}] - \mathbb{E}[\frac{\mu}{\sigma}]$$

Then it is clear to see that since $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are distribution parameters, i.e., fixed variables, and because the expectation of $X$ is $\mu$, we write:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{\sigma}] - \frac{\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{\mu}{\sigma} -\frac{\mu}{\sigma} = 0$$

Second, to show $Var[Z]=1$,we start from the definition of $Z$:

$$\begin{align*}Var[Z] &= Var[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}]\\ &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}Var[X-\mu]\\ &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}Var[X]\\ &= 1\end{align*}$$

This works for a theoretical distribution, but how does this apply to samples, i.e., suppose we have $x_1, x_2...x_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma),~ n \in \mathbb{R}$?

And more generally in statistics we use proofs that work for a theoretical distribution, but we generally do not prove them for samples, so why is that?

Comment: If you assume that both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known, the you can consider the standarised variables; in fact, standarisation can be performed for _any_ distribution with the first two moments.

Comment: what is it about sample that you want to prove?

Comment: I'm curious why we can apply standardization to a sample using the proof that only considers a theoretical distribution. Because in a sample you'd have to take the sample mean, which itself is a function of the data and isn't known. I feel like to actually justify it for a sample, we'd need something with the CLT or LLN

Comment: By known I mean fixed

Answer (score 1):

The usual framework in which we work with samples is one of parametric inference:  that is to say, we assume that the observed sample is representative of some underlying parametric distribution for which the parameter(s) is/are unknown; and as such, we are interested in estimating those parameter(s).

In this context, it is not the data that are unknown, but rather, the parameters that model the data that are observed, for which we must use the data to infer what their true values must be.

When we standardize a random variable, we are performing a location-scale transformation of that random variable in order to create a new variable with zero mean and unit variance.  This concept applies to a single variable or a sequence of variables.  In the IID case, it is purely an algebraic exercise in probability theory, since for such a sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ with common mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, each one is standardized by the same transformation  $$Z_i = \frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}$$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.  Notice how we have not made any assumption of normality.  This all comes from properties of expectation and variance.

Now, if we are talking about **estimation**, then what we would typically do is consider a **statistic** from the sample that relates to the goal of estimation.  That is to say, we want to calculate an estimator from the sample, but what it estimates could be the mean, or it could be the variance, or some other function(s) of the parameter(s) of the distribution from which the sample arises.  For instance, if we wish to estimate the mean, then typically, the estimator $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$ which we call the *sample mean*, is a good place to start, since its expectation will be $\mu$ and its variance will be $\sigma^2/n$, thus assuring that if these moments exist, the sample mean will be unbiased and consistent for $\mu$.

Then, the aforementioned standardization, if applied to this estimator, would take on the form
$$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.$$  This will have zero mean and unit variance; notice that there is the factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator, which is necessary since with increasing sample size $n$, the sample mean tends to have decreasing variance, and so standardizing requires us to take this into account.

A proof of this is straightforward and is really not any different than the proof for a single variable:

$$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \frac{n\mu}{n} = \mu,$$

and
$$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i] \overset{\text{id}}{=} \frac{n\sigma^2}{n^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n},$$

where "ind" means the equality holds because the $X_i$ are independent (thus all covariance terms are zero); and "id" means the equality holds because the $X_i$ are identically distributed (thus all variances are equal to $\sigma^2$).  These results reduce the problem to the single-variable case which you already established.

But again, you have not told us what estimator(s), if any, you are considering from the sample.  This is not a trivial matter:  for instance, there exists the (unbiased) *sample variance*

$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$$ which is an estimator for the true variance $\sigma^2$.  You could also standardize this estimator, because it is a random variable, and therefore has its own mean and variance.

Alternatively, some parametric models are parametrized by a location parameter that determines its support; e.g.,
$$f_X(x) = e^{-(x-\theta)} \mathbb 1 (x \ge \theta),$$ is a location-shifted exponential distribution.  The sample mean is not a good estimator of $\theta$, since $\operatorname{E}[X] = 1 + \theta$, not $\theta$ itself; in fact, the maximum likelihood estimator is the sample *minimum* $$\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} = \min(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) = X_{(1)},$$ which we also call the *first order* statistic.  This estimator happens to also be exponentially distributed but with mean $1/n$ and variance $1/n^2$; thus standardizing this estimator would require us to compute
$$Z = \frac{X_{(1)} - 1/n}{1/n} = n X_{(1)} - 1.$$
None of this has anything to do with the central limit theorem or the law of large numbers.  This is simply properties of the expectation and variance of parametric distributions, as they pertain to estimators of a sample.  You need to first describe a statistic before you talk about standardizing a sample.